# Tag view Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, tags, error-handling

OK i have a major problem under Joomla 3. When i generate a search URL for tagged items i get the following message and i am missing a lot of items:

**Notice: Array to string conversion in /www/htdocs/w00e40a7/pc-helfer/ego-new/libraries/cms/router/site.php on line 465** 
//** Turned error reporting off now so you don't see message anymore! **//

The URL for this is: 
`http://example.com/index.php?option=com_tags&view=tag&id[0]=26&id[1]=39&id[2]=64&id[3]=68&id[4]=69&types[0]=1`

when i create this search with a menu item everything is fine and the result returns me all items containing the exact tags:

```
http://example.com/test2
```

Anybody knows why this problem occurs and how to solve it?
Is it a Joomla Bug?

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting the URL using Joomla's helper class like so:

```
JRoute::_($myLink);
```